# Can I invest in the stock market as an international student?

Tags: stocks, student

Can an international student holding student resident permit in Germany, invest in the stock market? As international students are not allowed to start a business so does that restrictions also apply to investing in stock market?

If so, what is the procedure?

Comment: Do you have a bank account ? If so ask your banker. Otherwise go to a well-known bank that has brokerage accounts and ask them.

Comment: I'd... **try**.  They can only say "no", and won't kick you out... :)

Comment: Can you please link the legislation restricting you as an international student from "starting a business"? Given that we might can give you an indication if investments are also restricted. I don't think so, but I'm not a lawyer anyway.

Comment: As long as you are able to pay the money to own the stock and pay the tax(with a tax number), no broker will reject you.

Comment: @PeterWippermann: students have a different residence permit ("zum Zweck des Studiums") from the one needed to start a business ("zur Ausübung der selbständigen Tätigkeit"). They need different paperwork, and the study version explicitly says studying must be main purpose (basically full time student). The business one apparently asks for business plan, financial plans and prediced earnings etc. to be submitted. I'd think investing in stock market like a private person should be OK for a student, though - just like having a checking and/or savings bank accounts. OP may not be allowed to...

Comment: ... invest the money that is needed for their living expenses, though (but that's really just a guess).

Comment: thanks for replies. @cbeleites yes that is the reason i am asking that question, as a full-time student, investing savings in a stock as german saving accounts do not pay good returns. I understand that student visa prohibits students from being involved in any type of business, neither i want to change the student residence permit. I want to be sure whether investing in stocks is considered a business activity and does not violate any rule.

Comment: Maybe you should make an appointment with your municipal aliens department ("Ausländerbehörde") and ask for clarification there. You can also write a letter, so you can use their response as documentary proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a German registered address and bank account, you can. There are various German online banks that will give you an account within hours. Those require a smartphone and an international travel document. You indentify yourself via their app and services like [WebID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebID) or [PostIdent](https://www.deutschepost.de/de/p/postident.html). One (amongst many) possible setups would be [N26](http://n26.com/de-de/) (bank) and [degiro](http://degiro.de) (online broker). The latter requires you to be a German tax resident, which may or may not be the case for international students.

NB: I don't have a stake with any of those products/services in any way.